# How to check for convexity of function that is not everywhere differentiable?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convex-optimization

I have a question. I have just been introduced to the subject of convex sets and convex functions. 
I read this in wikipedia that a **practical test for convexity** is - 
to check whether the **2nd derivative** (**Hessian matrix**) of a continuous differentiable function in the interior of the convex set is **non-negative** (**positive semi-definite**).

So how to check for the convexity of functions like $f(x)=|x|$ which is differentiable at all points except at $x=0$ which coincidentally is actually its global minimum?

Thanks all for answering.

Comment: The book Boyd and Vandenberghe teaches many techniques for recognizing convex functions.

Comment: I am very new to this course... so I would like a detailed answer that is easy to understand for a layman. Kindly please help if possible.

Comment: Help us help you by *commenting* the answers already posted, asking for *specific* further explanations if indeed you need some.

Comment: It never hurts to know a bunch of inequalities with which to prove the convexity inequality you're aiming for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to check directly that the definition of a convex function is satisfied.

It's useful to know that any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ is a convex function.  Proof: If $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$, then
\begin{align*}
\| \theta x + (1 - \theta) y \| & \leq \| \theta x \| + \| (1 - \theta) y \| \\
&= \theta \| x \| + (1 - \theta) \| y \|.
\end{align*}
This shows that the definition of a convex function is satisfied.

When $n = 1$, the $2$-norm is just the absolute value function $f(x) = | x |$.  This shows that the absolute value function is convex.

A bunch of other techniques for recognizing convex functions are explained in the book Boyd and Vandenberghe ([free online](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)).

Comment: +1. Frankly, the derivative test is not particularly helpful in practice. Instead, most of the time you're proving the convexity of functions by showing how it is built up from *other* convex and concave functions in certain "convexity-preserving" ways. This "building block" approach to proving convexity is described in detail in Chapter 3 of B&V.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to write $f$ as the pointwise supremum of some family of affine functions, here $f=\sup\{g,h\}$ with $g:x\mapsto x$ and $h:x\mapsto-x$, since every such supremum defines a convex function and every convex function can be written as such a supremum.

Comment: This is definitely a very effective method, whenever it is applicable.